# Python: How do you reference the current class in declaration phase?

Tags: python, class, this, target, self

I'm trying to avoid having to create 2 classes for my AccessorFunc system by being able to target a class that is being 'declared', not initialized.

Right now, I have to create 2 classes, and in the second, extend from the first and target the first. ie:

```
class ExampleBase( object ):
    pass
class Example( ExampleBase ):
    ## This creates self.__a, self._a, self.a, and also self.GetA( ), self.SetA( _value ), and more...
    __a = AccessorFunc( parent = ExampleBase, key = 'a', name = 'A' );
```

This then adds the Accessor functions, etc.. to ExampleBase instead of Example. The problem with this, is the __ is created in Example, so if someone creates from ExampleBase they'd lose access to the reference to the accessor object which contains many helpers...

I would like to be able to just do something like this:

```
class Example( object ):
    ## Creates self.money ( Points to getter and setter / ie: property ), self._money ( data storage, raw - same as calling self.GetMoneyRaw( ) which could return None ) and self.__money ( Accessor object reference ) -- Note: setting Default doesn't mean it will initialize this default value. The raw data can be set to None, at which point the default is used. If the value is set, then it uses that value. Values are not set if an incorrect data-type is used.
    __money = AccessorFunc( parent = this, key = 'money', name = 'Money', allowed_types = ( int, float ), default = 0.0 );
```

And, while the AccessorFunc system works beautifully and lets you avoid having to create hundreds of lines of repetitions for simple classes, and also generate other unique helpers such as Has*, or CanAfford( _x ) attached to the money accessor, and so much more...

I am still limited that I have to create 2 objects... The reason I have to do __ = ...; is because __ is internal and I can't seem to generate it externally... So it makes a useful declaration point as the rest have no issues.

Is it possible to target the current class in this way? You'd think yes - some way - but using the class-name doesn't work because the class doesn't 'exist' yet, but, while it is being built there must be some reference to the object being built... Does anyone know the reference?

Thanks!

Edit: A few have asked for examples of what my AccessorFunc system looks like...
Here is a basic example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/km8igw1oaj5fftc/accessorfunc_create_get_set_name_functions.py?dl=0

The other version is https://bitbucket.org/Acecool/acecoolcodemappingsystem/src/master/Acecool.py -- but the newest version is properly packaged in AcecoolLib.util.accessor and when I complete the version 1.0.0 of Acecool Code Mapping System, will be included with it - or added as a new repo and linked....

Right now it is a mess - but, I create something like 26 named functions and several object functions for helpers... So with a single line I can reset a ton of commands. One instance is with mapping code - I can quickly and easily reset the stored data with a single line, instead of 10+ lines as a single helper function.

With the properties also being created, it allows you to use the keyed names, or you can use the named functions. It just depends on your taste, but some of the helper functions are so incredibly useful. It also makes it so that instead of writing thousands of mundane lines, I can write a few and have all of the features I need built in. If there is an issue - I update one area instead of hundreds of functions. etc... etc.. etc..

But, I'm still interested in getting access to the object while being loaded into memory... There must be somewhere since it goes line by line - and class X is called prior, so there must be some debugging function to allow me to get that automatically...

That way I don't need the ExampleBase pass Example ... __x = AccessorFunc( parent = ExampleBase, ... ) system... I could just do __x = AccessorFunc( ... ) and ignore parent, etc... One less arg and automatically grab the Example object, instead of Example base...

Comment: Also, if there is a way to target the current class while a class is being loaded into memory, but not being initialized, etc.. then I could make the parent vararg optional making the system easier to call..

Comment: Also, even though the AccessorFunc system can save me from having t write hundreds of lines in a file, and add additional functionality to getters / setters, create documentation, and so much more... This one problem is an annoying one. In all of my education I have never had this covered.. Hell, they never even covered properties and I had to learn them for myself. Also, the fact that no default AccessorFunc system exists by default ( ie: 1 line to create multiple ) is annoying... Many other languages have it. The property system is nice, but takes up many lines when only 1 should be needed

Comment: `AccessorFunc` looks like it is defining some kind of custom descriptor (or several of them); what does its definition look like? It seems more likely that you don't need to pass a reference to the parent at all, as `__get__` et al. already receive the class of its invoking object as an argument.

Comment: Why are you even using an `AccessorFunc`? Don't write getters and setters in Python. They are not necessary, certainly not boilerplate getters and setters.

Comment: Well, I like them because I can add a ton of functionality to them. Yes, getters and setters may not be 'necessary', however they are quite useful to easily ensure data-type lockouts, callback functionality, and much much more. Also, I wouldn't want a __get__ function packed with thousands of lines.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Yeah, normal / simple getters and setters aren't necessary unless you prefer calling a function... But, if the functions add additional features such as data-type protection, callback support, dynamic function overrides / hierarchy support, and more... then they can be quite worth it.

Comment: As an aside, your code has some strange things, e.g. `TYPE_LIST    = type( [ ] );` That can simply be `TYPE_LIST = list`. Don't add semicolons either

Comment: Python allows the use of semi-colons, but doesn't require them. I use them because they are part of my coding standard. Additionally, they allow you to delimit multiple statements on a single line if necessary, and they even make processing the code via outside source easier. I also use tabs because a 1MB file with spaces usually ends up being 100kb with tabs. Big difference.

Comment: Also, I do agree, in some regards, for the type( [ ] ) thing - I didn't know off the top of my head the data-type reference used for list so I used this to ensure it works. That method would also be future-proof if the reference ever changed. It does look cleaner to just use list, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always initialize such an attribute after the class is defined:

```
class Example:
    pass

Example.__money = AccessorFunc(parent=Example, key='money', name='Money', allowed_types=(int, float), default=0.0)
```

Comment: The __ won't be added, though, as __ designates 'internal' variables which can't be accessed from the exterior.. from my testing, doing it that way never provided me with the same results, either.. __ didn't get added or it became external and either acted as a static value, or not at all.. Even if it was able to function - which it didn't for my system, it still doesn't look nice doing it that way.

Comment: But, I will double-check it to verify. I use so many different languages it is quite possible I tried it in another language - but I am confident that python does have the _ local type and __ internal type structure. It could also be that it didn't let me do it dynamically, ie: if I did AccessorFunc( parent = Example, ... ); without Example.__money = ...; .. It could've also been another issue where if you don't add it in the Base, then if you add a function within Example, and try to call GetMoney( ) or .money, then it will not exist or you'll get a halting error.

Comment: It was one, or all of those reasons why I didn't use that method. Internal, function undefined error, couldn't define __ externally, even though I could define __ internally to parent because extension, doesn't look nice ( personally, if I were to do it that way I'd prefer to pre-declare, ie: above the object, which isn't something you can do ), etc...

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of `AccessorFunc`? It's hard to understand from your description what `AccessorFunc` actually does, which is vital to the understanding of the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: AccessorFunc adds getters and setters. These are quite common, and useful for reducing repetitive coding. I can write a single line, to save me hundreds of lines for simple functions. The other thing, is it creates properties which use those getters and setters.

Comment: Say I was creating a currency system - the most mundane task of this system is keeping track of how much money someone has, seeing if they can afford something, etc... It is just using simple getters and setters... So, I can use an AccessorFunc to make this final object much shorter, and complete the same task ( or better, actually, because there is no repetition, I have 1 area to fix anything if there is an issue, etc.. ). In short, AccessorFuncs in my context add these getters / setters, but also allow type verification and other features so a setter never sets an incorrect data-type, etc..

Comment: ie: if I do Example.__money = AccessorFunc( parent = Example, name = 'Money', key = 'money' ); then it will create self.money, self._money, and self.__money ( via the initialization of using Example.__money = ...; -- It will also create self.GetMoney( ), self.SetMoney( value ), and more. So I could do self.money = 100; and it would be identical to calling self.SetMoney( 100 ); I could also use self.AddMoney( 100 ) and it'd be the same as self.money += 100; I could easily create a CanAfford function in the declaration.

Comment: Basically, I create something like 16 object functions once per object, and I create 26 functions per name. -- The functions 
.<Get><N>
.Get<N>Raw
.Is<Name>Set
.Get<N>ToString
.Get<N>Len
.Get<N>LenToString
.Get<N>DefaultValue
.Get<N>Property
.Get<N>Accessor
.Get<N>AllowedTypes
.Get<N>AllowedValues
.Get<N>BaseAllowedTypes
.Get<N>BaseAllowedValues
.<N>HasGetterPrefix
.Get<N>GetterPrefix
.Get<N>GetName
.Get<N>GetKey
.Get<N>AccessorKey
.Get<N>DataKey
.Set<N>
.Add<N>
.Pop<N>
.Reset<N>
.Get<N>Helpers
.Get<N>Output
.Get<N>GetterOutput -- for the named functions ( Money )

Comment: Dynamic functions are nothing new, AccessorFuncs are the grouping of these dynamic functions. Simple examples are just saying AccessorFunc( O = Object, name = "Something", data_key = "somewhere" ); and the GetSomething, SetSomething functions get added to Object, and the data is stored in the somewhere reference. In Python, you can use properties but you don't get 'functions', which I do prefer but I also like how Python handles properties. Letting you do self.x = 123; and it going through a function. or self.x for the getter. etc.. so with my system, it does both and they're extensive.

Comment: I have a way for you to view it: https://bitbucket.org/Acecool/acecoolcodemappingsystem/src/master/Acecool.py -- Right now everything is in 1 file, and it is ugly. Part of my recode has me making a proper package. AcecoolLib.util.accessor = the new location for it in my local example. A simpler example is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/km8igw1oaj5fftc/accessorfunc_create_get_set_name_functions.py?dl=0 -- but it doesn't have the property system at the time of posting. I'll add it, the link should remain the same. With this, you get GetMoney, GetMoneyToString, SetMoney functions.

Comment: @Acecool note, double-underscore name-mangling is not for "internal" attributes, its to prevent name collisions in subclasses. Don't use it as a cheap substitute for access modifiers. That isn't what it is meant for, and that isn't what it gives you. In python, non-public members are conventionally denoted by the *single* underscore